# database query returning all values instead matching the entered column detail

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am developing a android application where user can search his details by filling any of the  column in multiple field form, no need to fill all the field, just has to enter any one column. But the Problem is instead of matching the entered field column it is displaying whole database.i tried filling 1 field , 2 field whatever i fill or even just click submit without entering anything it return whole database! where am i wrong?

**Search.java**

```
public class Search extends Activity {

SqlHandler sqlHandler;
EditText txtname, txt_relative_type, txt_father, txt_id, txt_part, txt_sl,
        txt_age, txt_house, txt_poling, txt_section, txt_ac_name,
        txt_ac_no;
ImageButton reset_btn, submit_btn;
RadioButton RdioBtn_male,RdioBtn_female;
ListView lvCustomList;
String intentname,intentacno,intentpartno,intentpoll,intentsl,intenthouse,intentAc_name,intentRelative,intentfather,intentage,intentsection;
String name1,acno,part,poll,sl,house,Ac_name,Relative,father,age,id,section,intentid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    txtname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txt_relative_type = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    txt_father = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    txt_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    txt_part = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    txt_sl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    txt_age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    txt_house = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    txt_poling = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    txt_section = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    txt_ac_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    txt_ac_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    reset_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    submit_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);



    submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name1 =  txtname.getText().toString();
            acno =  txt_ac_no.getText().toString();
            part =  txt_part.getText().toString();
            poll =  txt_poling.getText().toString();
            sl =  txt_sl.getText().toString();
            house =  txt_house.getText().toString();
            Ac_name =  txt_ac_name.getText().toString();
            Relative=  txt_relative_type.getText().toString();
            father =  txt_father.getText().toString();
            age =  txt_age.getText().toString();
            id =  txt_id.getText().toString();
            section =  txt_section.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent (Search.this,Listdisplay.class);
            i.putExtra(intentname, name1);
            i.putExtra(intentacno, acno);
            i.putExtra(intentpartno, part);
            i.putExtra(intentpoll, poll);
            i.putExtra(intentsl, sl);
            i.putExtra(intentAc_name, Ac_name);
            i.putExtra(intentRelative, Relative);
            i.putExtra(intentfather, father );
            i.putExtra(intentage, age);
            i.putExtra(intentid, id);
            i.putExtra(intentsection, section);
            i.putExtra(intenthouse, house);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    reset_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtname.setText("");
            txt_relative_type.setText("");
            txt_father.setText("");
            txt_id.setText("");
            txt_part.setText("");
            txt_sl.setText("");
            txt_age.setText("");
            txt_house.setText("");
            txt_poling.setText("");
            txt_section.setText("");
            txt_ac_name.setText("");
            txt_ac_no.setText("");
        }
    });
    }}
```

**Listdisplay.java**

```
  public class Listdisplay extends Activity {

    ListView lvCustomList;
    String intentname,intentacno,intentpartno,intentpoll,intentsl,intentAc_name,intentRelative,intentfather,intentage,intentid,intentsection,intenthouse;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchlayout);
         Intent myIntent = getIntent();
         String name_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentname);
         String acno_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentacno);
         String part_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentpartno);
         String address_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentpoll);
         String sl_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentsl);
         String area_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentAc_name);
         String guardian_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentRelative);
         String father_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentfather);
         String age_search1 = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentage);
         String idcard_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentid);
         String section_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intentsection);
         String house_search = myIntent.getStringExtra(intenthouse);
         lvCustomList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         showList(name_search,acno_search,part_search,address_search,sl_search,area_search,guardian_search,father_search,age_search1,idcard_search,section_search,house_search);
    }

    private void showList(String name_search,String acno_search,String part_search, String address_search,String sl_search,String area_search,String guardian_search,String father_search,String age_search1,String idcard_search,String section_search,String house_search ) {

        SqlHandler sql = new SqlHandler(this);
        ArrayList<contactlistitems> contactlist = new ArrayList<contactlistitems>();
        contactlist.clear();

        String query="SELECT  * FROM VoterSearch WHERE name LIKE (case when '"+name_search+"'!='' then '%"+name_search+"%' else name end) and PollAddress LIKE (case when '"+address_search+"'!='' then '%"+address_search+"%' else PollAddress end) and Relation LIKE (case when '"+guardian_search+"'!='' then '%"+guardian_search+"%' else Relation end) and FatherName LIKE (case when '"+father_search+"'!='' then '%"+father_search+"%' else FatherName end) and AcName LIKE (case when '"+area_search+"'!='' then '%"+area_search+"%' else AcName end)"
        +" and Section LIKE (case when '"+section_search+"'!='' then '%"+section_search+"%' else Section end)"+" and IdCard LIKE (case when '"+idcard_search+"'!='' then '%"+idcard_search+"%' else IdCard end)"+" and SlNo = (case when '"+sl_search+"'!='' then '"+sl_search+"' else SlNo end) and AcNo = (case when '"+acno_search+"'!='' then '"+acno_search+"' else AcNo end) and PartNo = (case when '"+part_search+"'!='' then '"+part_search+"' else PartNo end)"
        +" and HouseNo LIKE (case when '"+house_search+"'!='' then '%"+name_search+"%' else HouseNo end)"+" and Age BETWEEN (case when '"+age_search1+"'!='' then '"+age_search1+"' else Age end)"+" AND (case when '"+age_search1+"'!='' then '"+age_search1+"' else Age end)";

               Cursor c1 = sql.selectQuery(query);
               Log.i("Error","error");

               if(c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0)
               {
                   Log.i("Error","error");
                   if(c1.moveToFirst()) {
                       do {
                           contactlistitems contactlistitems = new contactlistitems();
                           contactlistitems.setname(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("name")));
                           contactlistitems.setrelative_type(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Relation")));
                           contactlistitems.setfather(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("FatherName")));
                           contactlistitems.setid(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("IdCard")));
                           contactlistitems.sethouse(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("HouseNo")));
                           contactlistitems.setsl(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("SlNo")));
                           contactlistitems.setage(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Age")));
                           contactlistitems.setpoling(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("PollAddress")));
                           contactlistitems.setsection(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Section")));
                           contactlistitems.setac_name(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("AcName")));
                           contactlistitems.setac_no(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("AcNo")));
                           contactlistitems.setpart(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("PartNo")));
                           contactlistitems.setSex(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Sex")));
                           contactlist.add(contactlistitems);

                       } while (c1.moveToNext());
                   }
               }
               c1.close();


               ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(Listdisplay.this, contactlist);
               lvCustomList.setAdapter(contactListAdapter); 

    }
}
```

**ContactListAdapter.java**

```
    public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<contactlistitems> contactlist;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<contactlistitems> list) {
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        contactlist = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contactlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contactlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.house = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.father = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                holder.sex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                holder.part = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText(contactlist.get(position).getname());
            holder.house.setText(contactlist.get(position).gethouse());
            holder.father.setText(contactlist.get(position).getfather());
            holder.sex.setText(contactlist.get(position).getSex());
            holder.part.setText(contactlist.get(position).getpart());

            return convertView;
        }



   static  class ViewHolder
     {
        TextView name,house,father,sex,part;
     }

}
```

I believe that the query is perfectly right! dont know from where its going wrong, is it passing values from class search to listadisplay through intent causing problem am not sure. Kindly help with this

Comment: have you tried running your query on the database itself and see if it returns correct result?

Comment: Are you sure about the query? "SELECT *" will return ALL columns.

Comment: Dynamically value is assigned and there are conditions which i guess cant run directly on database!!

Comment: Why do you construct a query with multiple "(case when [...])". This seems like a bad idea since you can do that in java with just one tenary operator each. You do know that the query has to be parsed by the database, right? Why not let your code do a little more to produce a simpler query? Also the construction of the query is not really [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Just one function could make the whole query construction shorter *+* more readable

Comment: @fabian actually am not good with the database, i searched query for above condition online and couldn't find one. My colleague gave me this query has it worked in other different project, so i took this and did changes. I really don't have any idea with ternary operators? could you kindly help me with this?

Comment: @user2861229: After a closer look it seems like in the case of empty `String`s produce conditions like "name LIKE name". Since they allways evaluate to TRUE and it's a conjunction, you can leave these parts out in that case. However that way constructiong the query becomes a bit more complicated. (You do not need the WHERE at all if all strings are empty) That unfortunately doesn't fit in a comment. Since it's not a answer to the question, I will not post it as answer to *this question*. Using StringBuilder may slightly improve the performance of query construction when you destinguish cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i tried with the live database the query was working fine. problem was whole data base was returned instead of match, hence the query may be returning null, now have to look for code. When i tested the value which i got through getIntent() it was not receiving value, hence the problem was with intent, value was not sent.  error was just to enclose double quote in intent and getintent

at Search.java double quote parameter

```
i.putExtra("intentname", name1);
```

at ListDisplay.java

```
String name_search = myIntent.getStringExtra("intentname");
```

And it worked